# Name collision between external documentation pages with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to link several libraries documentation in my Doxygen documentation via .tag files.

The problem is, each of those libraries contains additional .dox pages with the same name.

The structure would look like that:

- Library1

  - page.dox
  - other files correctly handled
  - library1.tag
- Library2 (which links library1.tag)

  - page.dox
  - other files correctly handled
  - library2.tag
- Main Project linking both .tag files

  - page.dox
  - other files

In the Main Project documentation "Related pages" list, I only get the following links:

- Library1 (external) (just as expected)
- page (external) (this is actualy the page.dox of Library1, not as expected)
- Library2 (external) (just as expected)

the page.dox from Main Project is nowhere.

(The same happens in the documentation of Library2: its own page.dox is hidden by the Library1 page.dox)

How can I force Doxygen to differentiate between the different page.dox files without renaming them?