# DoxygenLayout.xml parsing not finding explicit link request

Tags: doxygen

I am migrating from doxygen 1.8.4 to 1.8.8. My DoxygenLayout.xml file has an entry like this:

```
<tab type="user" url="@ref FAQ" visible="yes" title="FAQ" intro=""/>
```

In my Doxyfile, my `INPUT` includes "faq.htm" and I see in the Doxy output:

```
Reading /git/bfg_iOS_sdk/bfg_internal/docs/htmlFramework/faq.htm...
```

My "faq.htm" file begins like this:

```
/** 
\page FAQ Frequently Asked Questions
\ingroup FAQ
\{
```

With Doxy 1.8.4, there was no issue. In 1.8.8 I see these warnings:

```
explicit link request to 'FAQ' in layout file 'DoxygenLayout.xml' could not be resolved
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I am (and have been) using these file patterns:

```
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.m \
                         *.mm \
                         *.html \
                         *.h \
                         *.htm
```

I continue to see these warnings with Doxygen 1.8.10, and my doc set fails to build properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you are referencing the FAQ group in your DoxygenLayout.xml, but no file is associated with that group.

In this case, the reason is probably because your html file is not being read and parsed by Doxygen. This is because the default DoxygenConfig FILE_PATTERNS parameter does not include html by default.

Try changing your FILE_PATTERNS to include html and all other desired extensions, perhaps like this:

```
FILE_PATTERNS = *.html *.htm \
                *.c *.cc *.cxx *.cpp *.c++ *.java *.ii *.ixx *.ipp *.i++ \
                *.inl *.idl *.ddl *.odl *.h *.hh *.hxx *.hpp *.h++ *.cs \
                *.d *.php *.php4 *.php5 *.phtml *.inc *.m *.markdown *.md \
                *.mm *.dox *.py *.f90 *.f *.for *.tcl *.vhd *.vhdl *.ucf \
                *.qsf *.as *.js
```

You can also change EXTENSION_MAPPING to determine which parser will be used for your HTML file, since there is not a default HTML parser. The syntax you mentioned worked fine for me.

I am not sure why this changed from version 1.8.4 to 1.8.8. This [bug report](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/52cb086da66533332962f2bf9cb35772e980c092) for version 1.8.10 implies that this is a common mistake, and the developers even added documentation to clarify this behavior.

*Note from the OP --*
I needed this mapping:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = htm=Objective-C html=Objective-C
```

Comment: [Related Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139061/name-collision-between-external-documentation-pages-with-doxygen) but more strict, and unanswered.